# how do i get string like "aaa-23" from "aaa-23-34" in jquery?

Tags: javascript

For example-1 : I have string like "aaa-23-34" and I want string from this is "aaa-23"

For example-2 : `var str = "aaa-44-34-12"`

output should be `"aaa-44-34"`

That means I want string before the last hyphen.

Comment: what have you tried ? string operation is basic, and you should at least try.

Comment: Basic javascript would do.. hence I have retagged it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic string operations:

```
> "aaa-44-34-12".split('-').slice(0, -1).join('-')
"aaa-44-34"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple regex

```
"aaa-23-34".replace(/-\d+$/, '');
```

Ex:

```
var str = "aaa-44-34-12";
var txt = str.replace(/-\d+$/, '');
```